# Call nested namespace function javascript

Tags: function, namespaces

```
var namespace = {
    test: function() {
         //sample 1
         function nest(param) {
            console.log('a '+ param);
         }
         //sample 2
         this.nest = function(param) {
            console.log('b '+ param);
         }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain how to call and access the nested function? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `nest` function within the scope of `test` and it will only be accessible within `test`. The `this.nest` function is defined according to the context of your `test` function which is the `namespace` variable. This makes that version of `nest` accessible outside the `test` function even though you define it within the function body.

Alter your code to this and you will see the different console output;

```
var namespace = {
    test: function() {
         //sample 1
         function nest(param) {
            console.log('a '+ param);
         }

         nest('sample 1');

         //sample 2
         this.nest = function(param) {
            console.log('b '+ param);
         }

         this.nest('sample 2');
    }
}
namespace.test();
namespace.nest('sample 3');
```

This will produce the following output;

```
a sample 1
b sample 2
b sample 3
```

Some suggested reading on scope and context; [Understanding Scope and Context in JavaScript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks you @Dave Anderson for your answered. However, namespace.nest('sample 3'); doesn't work bro

Comment: @JebooScr how are you testing this? I've put that code directly in Chrome console as well as a JSFiddle and the console outputs all the log calls from places.